# Functional block digram of a HC-SR04?

Tags: block-diagram, hc-sr04

Can anyone illustrate a functional block diagram of a HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor? I understand how it works when it comes to the application but I would like to know how it works fundamentally as a system.

Comment: The schematic is available on the web. It's not particularly involved circuit wise.

Comment: This might help: HC-SR04 Ultrasonic Senor Wiring, Operation, and Python Programming Problem - RpiSE 2019apr18
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96647/cant-get-hc-sc04-sensor-to-work

Comment: And there is a schematic by Mbed: https://os.mbed.com/media/uploads/4180_1/hcsr04_schematic.svg